# gdalwarp from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3031 contains no data

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have a high resolution, optimized GeoTiff file in EPSG 4326 that I want to reproject into several other projections. Target projections EPSG:3857 (Mercator) and EPSG:3413 (Arctic stereographic) work fine, but EPSG:3031 (Antarctic stereographic) results in a GeoTiff with valid metadata, but no valid data content. In the latter case, the gdalwarp process that I use gives no errors, but finishes in a fraction of a second, already indicating that something is wrong. Any clues?
The gdalwarp version on my systems is 2.4.0

Some more info:

My procedure is:

```
    -> gdal_translate -of VRT -projwin -180 -40 180 -90 5p_tropomi_so2vcd_epsg4326_20200301_res0.01.tiff  vrt3031.vrt
    -> gdalwarp -tr 1100 1100 -srcnodata -999 -dstnodata -999 -t_srs epsg:3031 vrt3031.vrt test3031.tiff
```

The original epsg:4326 file has a resolution of 0.01 degree (about 1110 meter), so I specify -tr 1110 1110 in the gdalwarp commando. If I specify a much higher resolution, -tr 200 200 or even finer, the process proceeds fine.

Since the source file is large (about 800MB), I have made it available online:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZZoJeBPcDwZi5ywlu0eQqCHg4EkAPCV5

Here is the "gdalinfo -mm" result for the different rasters:

EPSG:4326 tiff:

```
  Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
  Files: s5p_tropomi_so2vcd_epsg4326/2020/03/s5p_tropomi_so2vcd_epsg4326_20200301_res0.01.tiff
  Size is 36000, 17998
  Coordinate System is:
  GEOGCS["WGS 84",
      DATUM["WGS_1984",
          SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
      UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  Origin = (-180.000000000000000,89.990000000000009)
  Pixel Size = (0.010000000000000,-0.010000000000000)
  Metadata:
     AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
    INTERLEAVE=BAND
  Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  89.9900000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 89d59'24.00"N)
  Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -89.9900000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 89d59'24.00"S)
  Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  89.9900000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 89d59'24.00"N)
  Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -89.9900000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 89d59'24.00"S)
  Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
  Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
      Computed Min/Max=-89.750,87.062
    NoData Value=-999
    Overviews: 18000x8999, 9000x4500, 4500x2250, 2250x1125, 1125x563,       563x282, 282x141
    Image Structure Metadata:
      NBITS=16
```

For the VRT file:

```
 Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
  Files: vrt3031.vrt
         s5p_tropomi_so2vcd_epsg4326/2020/03/s5p_tropomi_so2vcd_epsg4326_20200301_res0.01.tiff
  Size is 36000, 4999
  Coordinate System is:
  GEOGCS["WGS 84",
      DATUM["WGS_1984",
          SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
      UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
   Origin = (-180.000000000000000,-40.000000000000000)
   Pixel Size = (0.010000000000000,-0.010000000000000)
   Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
   Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=BAND
  Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (-180.0000000, -40.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 40d 0' 0.00"S)
  Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -89.9900000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 89d59'24.00"S)
  Upper Right ( 180.0000000, -40.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 40d 0' 0.00"S)
  Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -89.9900000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 89d59'24.00"S)
  Center      (   0.0000000, -64.9950000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 64d59'42.00"S)
  Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
      Computed Min/Max=-47.125,38.438
    NoData Value=-999
    Overviews: 18000x2500, 9000x1250, 4500x625, 2250x312, 1125x156
    Image Structure Metadata:
      NBITS=16
```

And finally for the erroneous EPSG:3031 file:

```
  Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
  Files: test3031.tiff
  Size is 10531, 10531
  Coordinate System is:
  PROJCS["WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic",
      GEOGCS["WGS 84",
          DATUM["WGS_1984",
              SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                  AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
          PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
          UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
      PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",-71],
      PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
      PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
      PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
      PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
      UNIT["metre",1,
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
      AXIS["Easting",EAST],
      AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","3031"]]
  Origin = (-5791903.876384493894875,5791903.876384493894875)
  Pixel Size = (1100.000000000000000,-1100.000000000000000)
  Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=BAND
  Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (-5791903.876, 5791903.876) ( 45d 0' 0.00"W, 23d 6'18.51"S)
  Lower Left  (-5791903.876,-5792196.124) (135d 0' 5.20"W, 23d 6'13.70"S)
  Upper Right ( 5792196.124, 5791903.876) ( 45d 0' 5.20"E, 23d 6'13.70"S)
  Lower Right ( 5792196.124,-5792196.124) (135d 0' 0.00"E, 23d 6' 8.88"S)
  Center      (     146.124,    -146.124) (135d 0' 0.00"E, 89d59'53.15"S)
  Band 1 Block=10531x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  ERROR 1: test3031.tiff, band 1: Failed to compute min/max, no valid pixels found in sampling.

    NoData Value=-999
```

Comment: please add the gdalinfo output for the input raster and the output rasters

Comment: You're right. Done.